# Symfony (3.2)'s ChoiceType - flipping key/values?

Tags: forms, symfony, key-value

I've been wrecking my brain, going from 2.7.x docs all up onto 3.2 which I am on and I fail to see why they removed `choices_as_values`. It is exactly what I require.

At this time I've got an input (don't ask why) with 3 values, 2 of which have the same name/label. It's what the customer wants and after much discussing I simply had to agree. So, i.e. I've got the following:

```
1 => Name
2 => Name
3 => Other Name
```

However, Symfony wants it received like this:

```
Name => 1
Name => 2
Other Name => 3
```

You can see the problem, the resulting array would become:

```
Name => 2
Other Name => 3
```

I'd be missing ONE value. So, what is the right way to go about this? I've tried numerous solutions, none of them worked. Keep in mind that the resulting value after submit must still be `1`, `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for flipping was that PHP only allows integers and strings to be array keys while actual choice values could be arbitrary PHP types. Usually, labels however are unique as duplicate keys will likely confuse users so it's easy to have them as the keys of the `choices` option value.

Anyway, if you need labels to be duplicated, you can pass a callback to the [choice_label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) that will return the label to be displayed:

```
$builder->add(ChoiceType::class, null, [
    'choices' => [
        1,
        2,
        3,
    ],
    'choice_label' => function ($value) {
        switch ($value) {
            case 1:
                return 'Name';
            case 2:
                return 'Name';
            case 3:
                return 'Other Name';
            default:
                return '';
        }
    },
]);
```